# How to format subsections with difference names

Tags: subsection

In my project, I had two types of different subsection, I want to name the first type "Lemma" and the other "Problem". For example, my subsections of lemma would be Lemma 1, Lemma 2, Lemma 3 ... while my problem subsections would be 1.30/25, 1.33/27, 2.17/35, 6.20/78 ... My lemmas is label in order while my problems's title need not to be in order, it just which exercíes that I choose to solve. So how can I make it ?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide a small compilable example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so people can better understand your problem and provide more effective help. There are specialised tools available for the lemmas. For the problems, `\subsection*{1.30/25}` might be best. Without code, it's hard to give more useful advice.

Comment: IIRC, theorems (lemmas etc.) are implemented as lists, similar to enumerate but each with a different counter.  Nesting them affects the indentation.  \section and \subsection also have levels, but they mostly affect the title size and TOC indentation.

Comment: thank you for your help, I really appreciate

Comment: @cfr  thanks for \subsection*{}, that was really spot on

Answer (score 0):

You can use LaTeX Theorems. [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems) is a good documentation.

> With "theorem" we can mean any kind of labelled enunciation that we want to look separated from the rest of the text and with sequential numbers next to it. This approach is commonly used for theorems in mathematics, but can be used for anything. LaTeX provides a command that will let you easily define any theorem-like enunciation.

Comment: when I use the code \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}, how to break new line after tiltle ? Since I don't want to state the lemma right after the title on the same line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can use [custom styles](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems#Custom_styles) taken from the documentation above. Use `\newline` in place of `headspace`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).